# Make tooltip position fixed

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I have been able to create the tooltips for my app. The tooltips content will comes from a DB and it is dynamic. Sometimes it will have two lines of text and sometimes it will have five lines of text. I am struggling to keep the position fixed regardless of what the content is. Is there anything I can try to fix this?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SX9en/) demonstrating what I am facing.

```
.tooltip:hover .dumClass {
    display: inline;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #DCA;
    background: #444;
    -moz-border-radius: 11px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 11px;
    border-radius: 11px;
}

enter code here
```

Comment: Do you want the tooltip to always hover over an element in the same relative position or should the tooltip appear in a fixed location?

Comment: In the same relative position, like in the fiddle.It will appear on top of the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS

```
.tooltip{position:relative;}
.tooltip .dumClass {
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    bottom:20px;
    left:0;
    width: 240px;
    line-height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SX9en/1/)